# Deleting multiple monitors displays

Tags: windows-10

How do I clear the multiple monitor configuration of a computer that is running Windows 10?  I have 2 monitors I'm using at different resolutions.  For some reason Windows 10 is reading my sound bar as a 3rd monitor setup.  The Active Signal Resolution for that display is wrong and I can't seem to correct it.  I've corrected the Desktop Resolution and saved multiple times, yet it's not correcting the underlying problems of the Active Signal Resolution.  How can I delete this display, as it shouldn't be listed as a display to begin with, it's a sound bar.  I've disabled it, but that doesn't delete it and it still affect the alternate monitor I'm trying to use.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the display in System -> Display and then setting "Multitple displays" to "Disconnect this display"?

Comment: Yes, I stated I've already disconnected that display.  Only place to do that is the System display panel.  I've also checked NVidia, as well as Intel Optane to make sure the settings are correct.  Yet, in the System display panel that's where I can see that this bogus display is set for the active display wrong.  Even after disconnecting that display, it's still affecting the display on the 2nd monitor, causing it to read to large.  I need to totally delete this 3rd display and I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

#### Please check that your drivers are up-to-date.

This sounds like a driver issue, but I do think that you already checked.

#### Try setting the resolution in the NVIDEA/AMD/Intel Control Panel

This may fix your issue as it should overwrite your windows setting.

#### You may to be able to delete the montior via the Device Manager (Windows+X and then press m).

Navigate to the Montiors section and delete the faulty Monitor.

[image: Navigate to the Montiors section and delete the faulty Monitor.]

Reboot your computer afterwards.
Windows may recognize your soundbar as monitor again (for whatever reason).
You may also try to disable it.

#### You may also try to have windows rediscover all monitors and solve the settings issue that way. [(from here)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows-10-reset-external-monitors-settings/b3a53cef-e54f-4410-b09e-6846fa297a3f)

1. Press Windows + R
2. Type regedit and hit ENTER.
3. If a message pops up saying "do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device" click YES.  A window called "Registry Editor" should show.
4. Locate this three registry keys:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration
>           HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Connectivity
>           HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\ScaleFactors

5. After finding them right click on each folder and select delete than yes.

Afterwards reconnect your monitors.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'd already tried everything except deleting the monitors, that was my next step.  I didn't know about the register keys though, great tip.  Thanks again and Happy Holidays

Comment: That worked great Alexander. My main display came up fine connected to my NVidia. Now the system didn't give me an option as to which Graphics to connect it to, but NVidia was the one I planned to connect it to anyway. I haven't re-connected the soundbar or the 2nd monitor yet. My question.... how do I insure that the 2nd monitor will be connected to my Intel Graphics 360? I have confirmed the soundbar, although not yet connected via HDMI is still working via Bluetooth. Thanks for all your assistance. You're all the best!

Comment: I am not sure, what you mean with "Now the system didn't give me an option as to which Graphics to connect it to". If you connect the cable to the graphicscard, the graphicscard will handle it, if you connect it to the onboard one (motherboard) then the cpu will handle it. Of course for that the cpu must support that too. Also if you are using both, you may have to reactivate the onboard one, as the BIOS usually deactivates the onboard one, when it detects another one.